# Exception when returning list back from a restful web service

Tags: rest

This is my service method..

```
@Produces({ "application/xml" })
@GET

  public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
    return hd.getAllCustomers();
  }
```

And this is my client side code.

```
Client c=Client.create();
        webResource= c.resource(getBaseURI());


        List<Customer> list=webResource.path("customers").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(List.class);
        System.out.println(list.isEmpty());
```

But when i m executing it is throwing me following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type interface java.util.List, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
```

Can you please help me reagarding this I m new to restful web sevices

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to return a List object as a result of a restful request? As far as I am aware that's not possible.

Even if that's not true The @Produces annotation is used to specify the MIME media types or representations a resource can produce and send back to the client. So your telling it produces xml and trying to return a List.

Comment: ok i get it but @Dan675 can you please tell me the way that i could return List of customers

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your Customer class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Customer {
```